# Spark dataframe query for sum

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I am having the following spark dataframe:

```
COLA   COLB  COLC
2019   A     10
2019   A     20
2019   B     30
2019   B     40
```

any function to generate the following dataframe?

```
COLA   COLB       COLC
2019   A          10
2019   A          20
      SUB_TOTAL   30
2019   B          30
2019   B          40
      SUB_TOTAL   70
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really specified how you'd like to group by your columns as the year is the same in all rows.
But you can use simple `groupBy` with `union` to achieve that:

```
# calculate sub totals grouping by COLB
sub_total_by_colb = df.groupBy(col("COLB")).agg(sum("COLC").alias("COLC")) \
            .select(lit(None), col("COLB"), col("COLC"))

# union original df with sub total df
df.union(sub_total_by_colb) \
    .sort(*[col("COLB").asc_nulls_last(), col("COLA").asc_nulls_last()])\
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----+----+
|COLA|COLB|COLC|
+----+----+----+
|2019|   A|  10|
|2019|   A|  20|
|null|   A|30.0|
|2019|   B|  40|
|2019|   B|  30|
|null|   B|70.0|
+----+----+----+
```

This is said, I would, however, suggest you have a look at multi-dimensional aggregations, this is better when you want to calculate sub totals.

Example using `rollup`:

```
df.rollup(col("COLA"), col("COLB")) \
 .agg(sum("COLC").alias("COLC"), grouping_id().alias("gid")) \
 .sort(*[col("COLA").desc_nulls_last(), col("COLB").asc_nulls_last()]) \
 .filter(grouping_id() != 3) \
 .select(col("COLA"), col("COLB"), col("COLC"))\
 .show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val tab = Seq((2019,"A",10),
(2019,"A",20),
(2019,"B",30),
(2019,"B",40)).toDF("COLA","COLB","COLC") 
tab.show  
val inter = tab.groupBy(col("COLA"),col("COLB")).agg((sum("COLC").alias("COLC")))  
val final = tab.union(inter).orderBy(col("COLC"))  
final.show
```

[image]